# Twilio voice call answering and talking

Tags: android, node.js, twilio

I have implemented android twilio call with this tutorial,
https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android
Everything works perfectly as they have mentioned. The call rings I can attend the call and listen to the VoiceResponse message I saved in server. My requirement is I need to talk to the one android twilio application to other android with same twilio application instead of receiving VoiceResponse message. If I make phone calls to actual phone numbers then I can talk and listen without any problem, but from application to application speaking does not work.

I am using node js as server code, the first calling person code is given below.

```
client.api.calls.create({
            url: url,
            to: phoneNumber,
            from: callerId,
        }, function(err, call) {
            if (err) { console.error('There was a problem starting the call: ', err); }
            console.log('Call with sid: ${call.sid} was started');
        });
```

xml response for url is

```
router.post('/callSecond', function(request, response) {
        const voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
        const dial = voiceResponse.dial({ callerId: 'client:al' });
        voiceResponse.say("Congratulations! You have received your first inbound call! Good bye. Welcome to Twilio! Welcome to Twilio!!!! Welcome to Twilio");
        dial.client("leo");
        console.log('Response :' + voiceResponse.toString());
        response.send(voiceResponse.toString());

    });
```

Can anyone please help me to find a solution for this, speaking to each other using twilio mobile application.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try what is described here: (https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android#bullet10)?

Comment: yes, i did. I can try to call from one phone to other using application and then call time count increases and i can't hear what i am saying in one phone to other phone @AlexBaban

Comment: What do you mean that the call from app to app doesn't work? Where does it break? Do you have any logs you can share for it?

Comment: I followed these tutorial to build my app,    https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android   https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-node .  when i call from one phone to other it will give the voiceResponse.say() i setup in the incoming function and gets disconnected, there is no time to talk to each other @philnash

Comment: Ok, I'm a little confused. You're trying to start a call between two android apps. Why are you initiating the call with Node.js and not in the application?

Comment: As per this document https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android we need to have a backend server to complete call, right? so when I call it ill go and check the url from twiml account and process through it. and this function gets called  client.api.calls.create({
            url: url,
            to: phoneNumber,
            from: callerId,
        }); It gets initiated from the app itself, then goto backend  I have already raised ticket in twilio for this , 1343231 . @philnash

Comment: When you are making app to app calls you do need a server, however that is not to initiate the call. When you create the access token on the server you set a TwiML Application SID for outgoing calls. The voice URL for the TwiML Application is where you need the server again, and it should return TwiML that connects your initial client with the client they are calling using [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client). Then, you initiate the call from your Android application and Twilio requests the TwiML from your voice URL and connects the call to the other client.

Comment: See step [10 in the quickstart instructions](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android#10-make-client-to-client-call) and the `VoiceActivity` for how this should work in the app.

Comment: Yes, I have followed those instruction. When i call from one app to another, it rings and i can accept the call and the it gives me Congratulation message and disconnects. What should i add in the code to keep the call going and talk to eachother. @philnash

Comment: So what is the code for initiating the call from Node.js for?

Comment: call initiating code is https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-node/blob/master/src/server.js page, here placeCall() function is starting the call and incoming() function is the VoiceResponse message comes out @philnash

Comment: Right, you need to initiate the call from the Android app using the Voice SDK. Not from the server. Here's the part of the quickstart that handles making the call from Android: https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/twilio/voice/quickstart/VoiceActivity.java#L328-L340. You have the `<Dial>` to `<Client>` in the code from your question. You can remove the `say` and it should work.

Comment: If i remove the say part it will disconnect in like 1 second. with this respons:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Dial callerId="+test_number"/></Response> @philnash I can share caller SID for this if you need

Comment: Ah, ok. The `<Dial>` shouldn’t be empty like that. Do you still have the line of code that calls `dial.client(‘leo’)`?

Comment: i already created a call in client.api.calls.create() part in the placeCall function, ryt? So i have to call back again to the first caller. that makes first person calling to answer the call again. I did that there the call will get connected and there is no voice transmitting. call will continue on. @philnash

Comment: So I replaced placecall() function with incoming function, by directly using dial.client() instead of client.api.calls.create() . It is working properly. Thank you @philnash . But I cannot hear any sound from any of the phone, my country has some banning of IP calls. does this affect the sound of the calls

Comment: Questions about countries banning this technology are best fielded by [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) as they have much better knowledge about how this might affect you than I do. Glad it's almost working though!

Comment: Yes. I have already raised a ticket with them. waiting for their reply. Thank you for your help @philnash. really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, hope you get this sorted out!

Comment: Hello @sha123, did you find any solution to your problem? I am stuck in the same issue. please help me to find out the solution for it. can you plz let me know where we need to work for the solution? from Backend or application?

Comment: I am also stuck in something similar situation. I too want to achieve one to one communication without any scripted text in Twiml or using URL which gets XML to speak. I want to as soon as the receiver picks my call i can talk with him from my application.